# Is there a default token available in ANTLR in case it doesn't match any of the already defined Tokens?

Tags: parsing, c#-4.0, antlr3

I have a requirement wherein I have written the Lexer token as :

```
 IF_LEXER_TOKEN: ('I')('F') (.)* ('E')('N')('D')_('I')('F')
 ANY :(options {greedy=true;}: .)* ;
```

But if the input is given as :

```
IF a>b then a=b END_IF
IF c>d then c=d
```

In this case the expected behavior is that it should use the token IF_LEXER_TOKEN for first line and ANY token for second line, but instead its considering the ANY token for both lines.
Kindly help.
Note:Due to some constraints I can't create a parser rule for the 
above scenario.

Comment: Why do you place all of your single letter tokens into an own parenthesis pair? Looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such default token. But you can easily create it:

```
ANY: .*?;
```

Best is to make this non-greedy to allow matching other tokens after that input. Btw: defining a complete sequence in the lexer has several drawbacks, e.g. error reporting cannot give you a good reason if a lexer rule fails. You have to handle all whitespaces explicitly. And you give up principles like that it normally does not matter how many whitespaces (including line breaks) exist between tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried creating the above token but its throwing a SystemOutOfRange Exception: can't look backwards more than one token.

Comment: This catch all rule must be the last lexer rule. Try also the greedy approach if it makes a difference.

Comment: The rule ANY: .*?; is throwing syntax error:NoViableAltException. Its the last lexer rule as u mentioned.

Comment: Did you try a few variations (like ANY: .; and make it a loop in places where you wanna use it)?

Comment: The alternative ANY:  (options {greedy=true;}: .)* ; is working! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you are on antlr4, hence I gave you the non-greedy variant from that. ANTL3 uses the options as you found out. Please accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the help.

Comment: Please ask a new question about that. QAs are not well suited for discussions.